# Find variables in a list of array

Tags: c#

Let's say I have a list of arrays with contains as below:

```
var listArray = new List<string[]>():
```

1st array = {code, ID_1, PK_1, ID_2, PK_2} //Somehow like a header

2nd array = {85734, 32343, 1, 66544, 2}

3rd array = {59382, 23324, 1, 56998, 2}

4rd array = {43234, 45334, 1, 54568, 2}

and these arrays will be added into 'listArray'.

```
listArray.Add(array);
```

what should I do for matching the variable inside the list?

e.g: if ID_1 of the array is '32343', ID_2 = '66544'.

Comment: @kingjia - Grant is right. It would be wiser if you put it in a DataTable. It'll be hard to maintain that if you keep using List<string[]>

Answer (score 0):

```
// create
var listArray = new List<string[]>():
string whatIWantToFind = "1234";
string[] mySearchArray = new string[] {"1234", "234234", "324234"};

// fill your array here...

// search
foreach(string[] listItem in listArray)
{
    // if you want to check a single item inside...
    foreach(string item in listItem)
    {
         // you can compare
         if(item == whatIWantToFind)
         {
         }
         // or check if it contains
         if(item.Contains(whatIWantToFind))
         {
         }
    }

    // to compare everything..
    bool checked = true;
    for(int i = 0; i < listItem.lenght; i++)
    {
       if(!listItem[i].Equals(mySearchArray[i])
       {
           checked = false; break;
       }
    }
    // aha! this is the one
    if(checked) {}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you create a class that contains all the data for one array, you can make a master array of those objects. For instance:

```
public class ListItem {
    public string code, ID_1, PK_1, ID_2, PK_2;
}
```

And then you can use this class:

```
var listArray = new List<ListItem>();
listArray.add(new ListItem(){ code = 85734, ID_1 = 32343, PK_1 = 1, ID_2 = 66544, PK_2 = 2});
listArray.add(......);
```

Then, to find the data, you can use a field accessor on the objects in the array:

```
foreach(var item in listArray)
{
    if (item.ID_1.equals("32343") && item.ID_2.equals("66544"))
        Console.WriteLine("Found item.");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var listArray = new List<string[]>
            {
                new []{ "code", "ID_1", "PK_1", "ID_2", "PK_2"}, 
                new []{ "85734", "32343", "1", "66544", "2"},
                new []{"59382", "23324", "1", "56998", "2"}
            };
 var index = listArray.First().ToList().IndexOf("ID_1");
 var result = listArray.Where((a, i) => i > 0 && a[index] == "32343").ToList();
```